# how to create dynamic data validation list on a column in excel such that if the source list changes then target should change

Tags: excel, excel-2010

i have a column A in workbook1.sheet1 which has data validation, whose values are appearing in drop down list from workbook1.sheet2.columnA. Now using the excels data validation feature i am successfully able to create this drop down. But the problem is when i update a list item in source i.e workbook1.sheet2.columnA it is not getting updated in workbook1.sheet1.columnA where this value was previously used. 
how can i make sure that whenever the source list items changes, correspondingly wherever the items have been referred they should also change?

Or any other way of achieving this?

TIA

Comment: What is in the source field for the valid values? It should look something like: =Sheet2!$A:$A

Comment: @ahoffer i am using direct data validation feature of excel. what are you referring to above. i am not clear?

Comment: This is what I am referring to: http://goo.gl/ZLBF0Q

Comment: I am doing the same thing but when u change value2 to some other value in the source list. value2 selected in entries column does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/05/25/create-a-drop-down-list-containing-only-unique-distinct-alphabetically-sorted-text-values-using-excel-array-formula/

It explains how to create a non-duplicate alphabetized list of values, how to create a dynamic named range, and how to use a named range in a data validation list.